# Uncaught error in rebar core when doing make rel

Tags: erlang, release, erlang-otp, rebar

I cloned a repo and trying to generate a release using **make rel** and see the following error. I am not sure whats wrong. Can anyone help ?

```
    Uncaught error in rebar_core: {'EXIT',
                           {{case_clause,
                             {error,
                              {function_clause,
                               [{filename,join,
                                 [{error,bad_name},"erts.app"],
                                 [{file,"filename.erl"},{line,406}]},
                                {rmemo,ets_tab,0,
                                 [{file,"src/rmemo.erl"},{line,187}]},
                                {rmemo,init,1,
                                 [{file,"src/rmemo.erl"},{line,181}]},
                                {gen_server,init_it,6,
                                 [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},
                                {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                 [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}},
                            [{rebar,run_aux,2,
                              [{file,"src/rebar.erl"},{line,218}]},
                             {rebar,main,1,
                              [{file,"src/rebar.erl"},{line,58}]},
                             {escript,run,2,
                              [{file,"escript.erl"},{line,747}]},
                             {escript,start,1,
                              [{file,"escript.erl"},{line,277}]},
                             {init,start_it,1,[]},
                             {init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
```

Thanks !

Im on mac OSX. 
I have rebar installed and in my $PATH. Verified by running rebar !

```
 rebar --version
 rebar 2.6.1 R16B03 20160602_012346 git 2.6.1-52-g9281b84
```

Comment: Please run `rebar --version` and add its output here.

Comment: @SteveVinoski running rebar --version gives rebar 2.6.1 R16B03 20160602_012346 git 2.6.1-52-g9281b84

Comment: The version of `rebar` you're running appears to be built from current master (latest commit Apr 2016), and so it definitely has the fix for this problem, which was fixed at rebar commit e025430 in Sep 2015. Is it possible that something you're building is supplying its own version of `rebar`?

Comment: Can you show your `Makefile`?